# Cheerio js take all addresses that contain text only

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I have the following code which takes me all the addresses.

I only need addresses that contain text.

Ex:

`<a href="https://www...." target="_blank">Text...</a>`

But the problem that there are addresses that contain an image, these addresses I would like to exclude them.

Ex:

`<a href="http://www..." target="_blank"><img src="http://www." border="0" alt=""></a>`

```js
$("div#posts > div > div > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(3)").each((_idx, el) => {
     $(el).find('a').each((_idx, el) => {
         let u = $(el).attr('href')
         if(u.includes("http")) element.add(u);
      })
})
```

Can you give me a hand?

Answer (score 1):

try selecting `a` that does not have `img` (or maybe any children, if there are other elements), with combination of [:has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) and [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

```
$(el).find('a:not(:has(img))').each((_idx, el) => {
    let u = $(el).attr('href')
    if (u.includes("http")) element.add(u);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter:

```
$('a').get().filter(a => $(a).text().match(/\w/)).map(a => $(a).attr('href'))
```